# insert into other table from main table value when button is clicked

Tags: php, yii

so i want to insert a value into a table when button is clicked, but the value to insert is taken from other function in the controller, how can i do that?

```
 public function actionInsert(){
    $description = $_POST['description'] ;
    $amount      = $_POST['amount'] ;
    $project     = $_POST['project'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO pengajuan VALUES ('test','1','projectA')";
    $db->createCommand($query)-execute();
 }
 public function actionSecondInsert{

 //so i want this function to do the same as previous function but insert 
 into different tables with the same value as the previous
 }
```

Comment: did you try `$this->actionInsert()` in actionSecondInsert ?

Comment: @Sakezzz it says the variable is  undefined

Comment: which variable?

Answer (score 0):

my solution is you put parameter into function actionInsert instead of making two function which has exact almost the same code.

```
 public function actionInsert($table){
    $description = $_POST['description'] ;
    $amount      = $_POST['amount'] ;
    $project     = $_POST['project'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ('test','1','projectA')";
    $db->createCommand($query)-execute();
 }
```

Comment: i can define the table name using the $table and it work without parameter but somehow it says my request is invalid when i put parameter on my function

Answer (score 0):

you can write function which is called in two actions

```
function insert($db, $table) {
     $db->createCommand()
    ->insert(
        $table,
        array(
            'column1'=>'test', // here you can write your columns
            'column2'=>1,
            'column3'=>'ProjectA'
        )
    );
}
```

then in action you can call like `$this->insert($db, $table);`